Kotlin Gradle Compilation Error: Incompatible Kotlin Version Metadata
I am trying to run a Flutter application on my physical device/emulator, but I am getting errors related to Kotlin version incompatibilities in Gradle.
Environment Details:
Flutter: 3.19.6
Gradle: 7.4.2
Kotlin: 1.8.0
JDK: 17
IDE: VSCODE

android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android/app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    namespace "com.example.flutter_pi"
    // ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion  // Remova ou configure corretamente se necessário

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_pi"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip

error:
e: /home/thmburso/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9264d74810240ea1f32e96d12ba2e7ba/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /home/thmburso/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9264d74810240ea1f32e96d12ba2e7ba/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /home/thmburso/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9264d74810240ea1f32e96d12ba2e7ba/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /home/thmburso/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/92d30563e91dfcaad35707ebf0a5dab0/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /home/thmburso/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e395fb178740444244ef6873c7735de9/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.6.1-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction

I have already tried updating the Kotlin and Gradle versions to 1.8.0 and 7.4.2, respectively, but I keep getting the same error.

Did you try using the 1.9.0 version?

Yes, I tried 1.9.0 and 1.7.1 as suggested in the error message.

Go to the build.gradle class and change the classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle to classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3"

I fixed the error. The issue was that I had applied Kotlin version 1.9.0 with apply false instead of using version 1.7.10:
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.0" apply false
